# System.Net.Http reference conflict possibly due to .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-standard-2.0

While building a .NET project I can see

> Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Net.Http" that
>   could not be resolved.

Furthermore, when making a call to `HttpClient.GetAsync(Uri)` I get an exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The `HttpClient` object shouldn't be null because I set DefaultRequestHeaders on it and no exception occurs at that point.

This is happening in a WebAPI project which references System.Net.Http v4.3.3 NuGet package which results in the project having System.Net.Http.dll v4.1.1.2.

This WebAPI project also contains a reference to another project (which contains the aforementioned `HttpClient.GetAsync(Uri)` call) which itself also references the System.Net.Http v4.3.3 NuGet package and which results in the project having System.Net.Http.dll v4.2.0.0.

Why do these versions numbers differ given that both projects are targeting .NET Framework v4.7.1?

I have tried `Update-Package -reinstall` as well as removing and re-adding the NuGet references.

Another point worth mentioning is that the referenced project (*i.e.*, not the WebAPI project) in turn references a .NET Standard 2.0 project which also references System.Net.Http v4.3.3. I've only had this problem since this innermost project was updated from .NET Standard 1.3 to 2.0.

So the chain is

WebAPI (.NET Framework v4.7.1)
        > System.Net.Http v4.3.3
        > Class library (.NET Framework v4.7.1)
            > System.Net.Http v4.3.3
            > Class library (NET Standard 2.0)
                > System.Net.Http v4.3.3

There has been a known compatibility problem between projects referencing .NET Standard 2.0 and System.Net.Http (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/484)) but that issue resulted in the yellow warning asterisk, whereas I don't have that.

Can anyone explain why the top two projects have differing version numbers for System.Net.Http despite referencing the same NuGet package, and whether my "Object reference not set... " exception is due to the conflict which is mentioned during the build output?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a simular issue which has to do with .NET Standard 2.0 and binding redirects. I solved it by adding the lines below to the .csproj file of the affected project (for me a unittest project). The issue is explained [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481).

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks @pfx - I had already tried that. I found a similar solution which works for me, so I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to <s>solve</s> work around this problem by commenting-out the binding redirect for System.Net.Http in the WebAPI project.

I'm not entirely sure *why* this works, but it does. I'll check back intermittently to see if I need to keep it commented-out.

Comment: The binding redirect might reappear when there is an update of the corresponding NuGet package.